# Logic redirect doesn't happen without clearing cookies on SPA

Tags: single-page-application, openid-connect

I am using react based SPA with OpenId authentication. Even though I have ChallengeAsync() called from the middleware as shown in code below, on refresh the page is not get redirected to login page to auth the user. It does redirect on when we do a hard refresh(ctrl+F5).
Can anyone please suggest what could be missing here?

```
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        // Must go before UseMvc
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {

                var result = await context.AuthenticateAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                context.User = result != null && result.Succeeded ? result.Principal : new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity());

                if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    await context.ChallengeAsync(new AuthenticationProperties { 
                        IsPersistent = true, 
                        ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(int.Parse(CookieExpiryInHours)) 
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    await next();
                }
        });

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
```